# Basis of polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> The set of polynomials $\{x^3 +x^2 +x, x^2 +x +1, x+1\}$ is linearly independent in $P_3$ but does not form a basis of $P_3$. Find a fourth polynomial that can be inserted to form a basis of $P_3$.

My first attempt at this was to add $x$ so:

$$\{x^3 +x^2 +x, x^2 +x +1, x+1, x\}$$

and I got $-12$ when I did the Wronskian.

Does this look right?

Comment: $x$ is OK. so is $1$, there are many choices.

Comment: In particular, it's nearly trivial to prove that any constant will do.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the definition of linear independence. If 
$$c_1(x^3+x^2+x) + c_2(x^2+x+1) + c_3(x+1) + c_4x = 0, $$
this implies that
\begin{align}
c_1x^3 &= 0 \tag 1\\
(c_1+c_2)x^2 &= 0 \tag 2\\
(c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4)x &= 0\tag 3\\
c_4x &= 0\tag 4
\end{align}
It's clear that $(1)$ implies $c_1=0$, so $(2)$ implies that $c_2=0$. Then $(4)$ implies that $c_4=0$, and hence $c_3=0$. Since you have $4$ linearly independent vectors in a space of dimension 4, they necessarily form a basis.